# Full screen (overlay status bar) alert activity

Tags: android, popupwindow

I wanna write an popup activity (similar to alert dialog) that is translucent, covering the status bar something looks like the screenshot below

[image: Sample]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Totally new to Android Development no idea what to do -.-;

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to write code for you, you are expected to do research, read the docs and try. We will then help fix what you have already got

Comment: Did I ask for code? An idea would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

try add this in your onCreate method before setContentView

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```